# Link Lists, invalid application of path to size incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

Im Getting an invalid application of path to size error when compiling my code but cant find the problem myself, can anyone help?

```
/*********************************************************
* Node to represent a packet which includes a link reference*
* a link list of nodes with a pointer to a packet Struct    *

**********************************************************/
struct node {
unsigned int Source;
unsigned int Destination;
unsigned int Type;
int Port;
char *Data;
struct Packet *next;
 // Link to next packet

//unassigned int source
//unassigned int destination
//int type
//unassigned int port
//char *data
//struct node  *next link to next node
};

typedef struct Packet node; // Removes the need to constantly refer to struct


/*********************************************************
* Stubs to fully declared functions below                *
**********************************************************/
void Outpacket(node **head);
void push(node **head, node **aPacket);
node* pop(node **head);

int main() {

/*********************************************************
* pointers for the link list and the temporary packeyt to    *
* insert into the list                                   *
**********************************************************/
node *pPacket, *phead = NULL;

/*********************************************************
* Create a packet and also check the HEAP had room for it   *
**********************************************************/
pPacket = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
if (pPacket == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: Out of Memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

This is only a snipet of the Full code but the break point happens on the line with:

```
pPacket = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is because you are using `struct Packet` with out defining it.

In your definition of `struct node`, you are using `struct Packet*`. But ther is nothing called `struct Packed`. Either you change the name of the structure, or change the element.

try the following:

```
struct Packet {
unsigned int Source;
unsigned int Destination;
unsigned int Type;
int Port;
char *Data;
struct Packet *next;
 // Link to next packet

//unassigned int source
//unassigned int destination
//int type
//unassigned int port
//char *data
//struct node  *next link to next node
};

typedef struct Packet node; // Removes the need to constantly refer to struct
```

Here, `struct Packet` and `node` are the same structure and there is no anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use construct:

```
typedef struct Packet { .... } node;
```

You named struct node, but pointer to next element inside it from type

`struct Packet *`.